# Hosting ASP.NET Core app on APACHE shows port on url

Tags: .net, windows, apache, asp.net-core, hosting

I have hosted my ASP.NET Core website on APACHE. The problem is that it shows port on the url i.e. **https://mywebsite.com:5001/** is what the browser shows on the url.

There are 2 ports opened on KESTREL.

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "MyHttpEndpoint": {
      "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "MyHttpsEndpoint": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
    }
  }
}
```

The redirect middleware is added to program.cs.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

The app is running properly see image:

[image]

The Apache config file code is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
    ErrorLog C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log
    #CustomLog C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols             h2 http/1.1
    ProxyPreserveHost     On
    ProxyPass             / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse      / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName            mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias           *.mywebsite.com
    ErrorLog              C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log
    #CustomLog             C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log
    SSLEngine             on
    SSLProtocol           all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder   off
    SSLCompression        off
    SSLSessionTickets     on
    SSLUseStapling        off
    SSLCertificateFile    C:/xampp/htdocs/aspnetcore/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/xampp/htdocs/aspnetcore/server.key
    SSLCipherSuite        ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I open the website url which is **mywebsite.com** on the browser. I see it's port 5001 added to it. See the below image:

[image]

Ideally I expect simply **https://mywebsite.com** on the browser url but not what I get. The docs that I referred is [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

The network tab of the chrome browser indicates the redirected to **https://mywebsite.com:5001** see the below image:

[image]

Something is wrong and I cannot figure it out. Any help??

Comment: Does the browser automatically redirect to that port? Or did you type it manually?

Comment: @Jonathan it redirects.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you shouldn't use `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`. If we go the [doc about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#require-https)

We can find `Note`

```
Apps deployed in a reverse proxy configuration allow the proxy to handle 
connection security (HTTPS). If the proxy also handles HTTPS redirection,
there's no need to use HTTPS Redirection Middleware. If the proxy server also
handles writing HSTS headers (for example, native HSTS support in IIS 10.0
(1709) or later), HSTS Middleware isn't required by the app. For more
information, see Opt-out of HTTPS/HSTS on project creation.
```

This is exactly your case as `Apache` is your reverse proxy, so it's better to handle redirection by `Apache` instead of by your ASP.NET app, as your app doesn't know that your `Apache` also listening on port `443`, it only know that its own `https` port is `5001` and this is why it's redirected to this port

To handle redirection in your case `Apache` config for port `80` should look something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
    Redirect permanent / https://mywebsite.com/
    ErrorLog C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log
    #CustomLog C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Of course your can keep redirection in your app, but to make it works your will need to use `AddHttpsRedirection` [doc example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#options)

And it should look like (based on example):

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
});
```

Port should be `443` because it has to be port of `Apache` not your app, as `Apache` will forward all requests to your app

Minimal working code

```cs
using System.Net;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/", () => "hello!");
app.Run();
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols             h2 http/1.1
    ProxyPreserveHost     On
    ProxyPass             / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ProxyPassReverse      / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ServerName            mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias           *.mywebsite.com
    ErrorLog              /var/log/apache2/error.log
    #CustomLog             C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log
    SSLEngine             on
    SSLProxyEngine        on # this is important
    SSLProtocol           all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder   off
    SSLCompression        off
    SSLSessionTickets     on
    SSLUseStapling        off
    SSLCertificateFile    /work/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /work/key.pem
    SSLCipherSuite        ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have tested it by removing redirection middleware and redirecting from apache itself. It works perfectly but the problem is that if we use redirection middleware then their is the problem. Suppose we want to use this middleware for doing other tasks too then their would be a problem.

Comment: Question is what task? Overall you have to think as whole context and flow `Browser ==> Apache ==> ASP.NET app` and what they know about each other, if first option is not for you use `AddHttpsRedirection`, anyway there is no perfect general solution for this as far as I know, so you have to provide what you want to achieve

Comment: I just now checked by adding your code - `builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection....` but no change at all.

Comment: I added minimal working code, when you have `AddHttpsRedirection` you must have also  `UseHttpsRedirection`

Comment: My fault you also need change `<VirtualHost *:443>` to use as proxy `ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:5001/` and `ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:5001/` because asp.net app was still getting `http` request instead of `https`

Comment: I tried just now with https://127.0.0.1:5001 as you said. same problem.

Comment: Where do you get redirected when you access [http://localhost](http://localhost) ?

Comment: when I open https://localhost it redirects me to https://localhost:5001/

Comment: Sorry I can't help without seeing what you have in `Program.cs`, if you have exactly what I wrote with no changes at all `options.HttpsPort = 443;`(do NOT change this port), it should work

Comment: I checked both the scenarios. As you said, `options.HttpsPort = 443;` is giving "too may redirects" error and app does not opens in the browser. As for microsofts `options.HttpsPort = 5001` it has no effect.

Comment: If you are getting `too many redirectes` probably in your `<VirtualHost *:443>` you are passing to `http` endpoint instead of `https`, you should have those 3 `ProxyPass             / https://127.0.0.1:5001/`, `ProxyPassReverse      / https://127.0.0.1:5001/` and `SSLProxyEngine        on`